# Set Nautilus file icon per extension

Tags: icons, gnome, nautilus

Is it possible to change the icon (not the emblem) of a file in Nautilus' icon view mode by means of its [extension interface](http://developer.gnome.org/libnautilus-extension/stable/ch01.html)?

It would be cool, I think, to see the album covers of MP3 files of embedded ID3v2 APIC frames while browsing folders with music. Until now, I am able to extract the picture and I copypastehacked some example code to add emblems and menu items to Nautilus. But neither the column provider nor the file info provider offer an obvious way to change the icon.

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180432/how-to-change-icon-emblem-of-a-directory-from-bash/2571132#2571132) suggests using `gvfs-set-attribute`, but I would rather extract the icon dynamically instead of creating a lot of unnecessary files somewhere.

Thanks in advance for any helpful suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not with the extension interface. The canonical way to create individual icons is to register a so called "thumbnailer" in the gconf database under `/desktop/gnome/thumbnailers`. For ID3v2 APIC frames, solutions are already available.