# Adding a badge to an icon in Python on Windows/OSX/Linux

Tags: python, filesystems, icons, finder, badge

I'm trying to figure out how to add and modify badge icons to individual files on the filesystem much like how Dropbox adds the sync icon to files. I want to do this across platforms and am looking to see what language would be best. Right now I think python is the candidate, but I'm open for other languages that this problem might already be solved in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I doubt there's a platform-agnostic library in any language to achieve your goal. I

For GNOME (and probably XFCE) the badge icons are called *emblems* and are manipulated via gvfs metadata. Here's how you can change the emblem via command line (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2571132/175349)):

```
$ gvfs-set-attribute $FOLDER -t stringv metadata::emblems new urgent
```

I'm pretty sure if you dig into the source of gvfs-set-attribute you'd figure out the API.

For KDE 4.x you can use kwriteconfig (taken from [here](http://kde-apps.org/groups/?mode=0&id=404&forumpage=0)):

```
$ kwriteconfig --file "$FOLDER/.directory" --group 'Desktop Entry' --key Icon /path/to/icon.png
```

On Windows you are supposed to [implement](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7484/How-to-overlay-an-icon-over-existing-shell-objects) an [IShellIconOverlayIdentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761265%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) COM interface.

For MAC... I don't know. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778855/how-can-i-conditionally-color-files-and-folders-in-the-os-x-finder) there's no official API to do that at least for Mac OS X 10.6.

Comment: Liferay Nativity is a platforma gnostic library.   It does not have Python bindings, but that would be a good place to start maybe.